# Bazaar (bzr) VCS: Copy/clone file with history? i.e. "bzr copy"?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

**Q:** Does [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) yet support the ability to duplicate a file and preserve history on both the original and cloned files?

A couple of years ago I was evaluating Bazaar for my company's VCS. There's a lot I really like about it, but one important factor ultimately led us in a different direction: the lack of a `bzr copy` (or equivalent). This may not be particularly relevant for some teams, but its a pretty common operation for us.

I know the issue was discussed extensively in the past (see references below), but I'm not clear on whether anything was ever implemented.

*References*

- [Article on the Bazaar website](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrFileCopies)
- [Question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32199/split-a-text-file-into-two-files-without-losing-revision-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably saw [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/217670), it has not been implemented yet and I'd be really surprised if it happens soon if at all :(

Comment: Tragic that such a promising project would neglect such an obvious and essential feature.